# Loop through JS object to return matching result of value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, javascript-objects

I have an object, full of salmon. I want to loop through and check whether salmon is fresh or frozen. If frozen, put in no pile, if fresh, put in yes pile. If ounces is less than 2 and more than 6, no pile, and if it matches 2-6, yes pile.

Then, with the yes pile, I want to loop through those keys and values to find the cheapest one, and print that out.

Here is what I have so far, but I seem to be stuck on looping through the big object in order to run the checks.

How do I do this?

```
function findSalmon(salmonInStore){
  var noPile, 
      yesPile; 
      var salmon = Object.keys(salmonInStore));
  for(var key in salmonInStore){

    if(salmonInStore.key.freshness !== 'fresh'){
      noPile.push(salmonInStore.key);
    } else {
      yesPile.push(salmonInStore.key);
    }
    if(salmonInStore.key.ounces < 2 && salmonInStore.key.ounces > 6){
      noPile.push(key);
    }else {
      yesPile.push(salmonInStore.key);
    }
  }
  return yesPile;
}

var salmonInStore = {
  salmon1 : {
    ounces: 1,
    freshness: 'frozen',
    price: 16
  },

 salmon2 : {
    ounces: 6,
    freshness: 'fresh',
    price: 10
  },

  salmon3 : {
    ounces: 2,
    freshness: 'frozen',
    price: 20
  },

  salmon4 : {
    ounces: 5,
    freshness: 'fresh',
    price: 1
  },

  salmon5 : {
    ounces: 3,
    freshness: 'frozen',
    price: 12
  }
}

findSalmon(salmonInStore);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we can sort the salmon list by price.

```
const salmonList = Object.keys(salmonInStore)
  .map(key => salmonInStore[key])
  .sort((a,b) => {
    if (a.price < b.price)
      return -1;
    if (a.price > b.price)
      return 1;

    return 0;
});
```

Then we can filter out the yes fish.

```
const yesPile = salmonList.filter((salmon) => {
 return salmon.ounces >= 2 && salmon.ounces <= 6 && salmon.freshness === 'fresh';
});

yesPile[0] // cheapest fish
```

Check out the fiddle for a working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/y1jg01wy/

Answer (score 2):

```
function findSalmon(salmonInStore){
var yesPile = [];
var noPile = [];
Object.keys(salmonInStore).forEach( (key)=> {
  var salmon = salmonInStore[key]

  if (salmon.freshness !== 'fresh' || salmon.ounces < 2 && salmon.ounces > 6){
    noPile.push(key);
  } else {
    yesPile.push(key);
  }
})
return yesPile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I seem to be stuck on looping through the big object in order to run the checks.

Objects are also known as *key/value* pairs.

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of an object. From then on you need *nested* loops and *dynamic value access* using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to get the value of a k/v pair based on the key you got when you used `Object.keys`.

Here's an example:

```js
var salmonInStore = {
  salmon1 : {
    ounces: 1,
    freshness: 'frozen',
    price: 16
  },

 salmon2 : {
    ounces: 6,
    freshness: 'fresh',
    price: 10
  }
}

Object.keys(salmonInStore).forEach(storeKey => {
  var salmon = salmonInStore[storeKey]
  // put per salmon logic here...

  Object.keys(salmon).forEach(salmonKey => {
    var value = salmon[salmonKey] // value for each key  
    console.log(value)
    // put per salmon value logic here...
  })
})
```

However if you plan on having arbitrary nesting levels - not just 1 level, you would need a recursive function to walk your salmons.

The above can be made more 'functional' by using `reduce` instead of `forEach` but that's another story.

The gist of the above is that you need `Object.keys` and `someObj[key]`. I've substituted your `for..` loops with `forEach` just for brevity.